# PKG_CONFIG_PATH has not been set when trying to configure Qt for Arm

Tags: linux, cross-compiling

I am using this to set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/dbus/lib/pkgconfig
```

after this I am trying to run the configure of qt using the following command

```
./configure -prefix /home/navani/Qt-4.6.3/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.3 \
-opensource -embedded arm -platform qws/linux-x86-g++ -confirm-license -release \
-no-rpath -no-fast -no-accessibility -no-sql-ibase -no-sql-mysql -no-sql-odbc \
-no-sql-psql -no-sql-sqlite2 -no-qt3support -no-mmx -no-3dnow -no-sse -no-sse2 \
-no-neon -no-optimized-qmake -no-nis -no-cups -pch -reduce-relocations \
-force-pkg-config -prefix /usr -no-armfpa -make libs -nomake docs -iconv \
-largefile -embedded arm -qt-decoration-styled -depths all \
-xplatform qws/linux-mx35pdk-g++ -make examples -make demos \
-examplesdir /usr/bin/qt4-examples -qt-gfx-directfb -qt-gfx-linuxfb \
-qt-gfx-transformed -no-gfx-qvfb -qt-gfx-vnc -qt-gfx-multiscreen -qt-kbd-tty \
-qt-kbd-linuxinput -no-kbd-qvfb -qt-mouse-pc -qt-mouse-linuxinput \
-no-mouse-linuxtp -no-mouse-qvfb -qt-libpng -no-libmng -no-libtiff -no-gif \
-no-libjpeg -qt-zlib -qt-freetype -little-endian -stl -no-glib -no-openssl \ 
-no-dbus -no-opengl -shared -xmlpatterns -exceptions -no-multimedia \
-no-audio-backend -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-webkit -no-scripttools \
-no-sql-sqlite -nomake tools -svg -script
```

But I am getting an error saying

> PKG_CONFIG_PATH has not been set.  This could mean the host compiler's
>   .pc files will be used. This is probably not what you want.

Am I doing something wrong?? What should I do?

Comment: Invoke with: `env PKG_CONFIG_PATH="<path_list>" ./configure ...` ?

Comment: @BrettHale : this is also not working

Comment: @Jis: what does `configure --help` show ?